# Lazy Load ChildComponents in ParentComponent

Tags: angular

I'm trying my first application with lazy loading. I have a dynamically changed content which is changed when the user hits a menu point. Lets take this for example:

**menu.component.html**

```
<ul>
    <li (click)="changeRoute('information')">Information</li>
    <li (click)="changeRoute('personal')">Personal</li>
    <li (click)="changeRoute('blog')">Blog</li>
</ul>
```

**changeRoute function**

```
changeRoute(url) {
    this.router.navigate([url], {skipLocationChange: true});
}
```

**content.component.html**

```
<div id="content">
    <app-information *ngIf="router.url === '/information'"></app-information>
    <app-personal *ngIf="router.url === '/personal'"></app-personal>
    <app-blog *ngIf="router.url === '/blog'"></app-blog>
</div>
```

My problem now is, that when i load `content.component.html` inside my `app-routing.module.ts` via

```
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './content/content.module#ContentModule'
}
```

angular requires me to also load `information.component.html`, `personal.component.html` and `blog.component.html` but actually i would like to only load them, when the user hits a specific menu.

For completeness:

**content.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ContentRoutingModule } from './content-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ContentRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class ContentModule { }
```

**content-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ContentComponent } from './content.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ContentComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ContentRoutingModule { }
```

How can i achive, that the components, `information`, `personal` and `blog` are not initially loaded / needed, but when the user hits the menuItem for the component?

The exact error message from console is:

> app-information is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module
>
> app-personal is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module
>
> app-blog is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

As far as i understood lazyLoading correctly, there is no sense to include these components inside the parent component because they get initially loaded than - or am i wrong? I thought about a module for each single component, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to lazy load the content, you need to ensure you don't reference it (as you found). In order to accomplish this, you need to use routing.

So you need to change this:

```
<div id="content">
    <app-information *ngIf="router.url === '/information'"></app-information>
    <app-personal *ngIf="router.url === '/personal'"></app-personal>
    <app-blog *ngIf="router.url === '/blog'"></app-blog>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And then route each of the components into that router outlet. The components then become routed components instead of child components and the components no longer need to be referenced by the parent component ... allowing you to do lazy loading.

In your content component, you then set up the route configuration, something like this:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'information',
    component: InformationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'personal',
    component: PersonalComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'blog',
    component: BlogComponent
  }
])
```